# Find the $\gcd(a^{2^m} + 1, a^{2^n} + 1)$ if $m>n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

From what I know, the question can be solved from congruence modulo or without. Since the question is before the concept of congruence modulo in the book which I am using, I guess a solution without using modulo should be the answer.

Here's what I have tried till now -

Let $a^{2^n}$ = k

$a^{2^m} = a^{2^{n+r}}$ (where $r ≠ 0$)

$a^{2^m} = a^{2^n\cdot 2^r} + 1 = k^{2^r} + 1$

The expression then simplifies to $\gcd(k+1, k^{2^r} + 1)$

Ideally, there should be two cases - one where $k$ is odd and one where $k$ is even. But I am unable to find a solution on that basis. Thanks in advance!

*Source : Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics*

Comment: Hint before scrolling down to the answer: let $p$ be a prime dividing the gcd. Then $ a^{2^{m}} = -1 \pmod{p}, \quad a^{2^{n}} = -1 \pmod{p}.$ Try to deduce that $p=2$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, I found the duplicate using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(a%5E%7B2%5Em%7D%2B1%2Ca%5E%7B2%5En%7D%2B1)%24&p=1). Note that duplicate question was closed as a duplicate of $3$ other questions, and there are quite a few additional duplicates on this site. In addition, the Approach0 search results include quite a few AoPS threads, e.g., [Pre College Question](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1471056p8535458), [How solve this NT problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1711827p11041106), etc.